# Sling Mapping Rewrite Rules do not rewrite paths in meta tags

Tags: aem, sling

I have sling mappings setup that rewrite outgoing paths to the external URL.  An example of this rewrite:
`/content/www-sitename/home.html` would be rewritten to `http://www.sitename.com/home.html`

I have also configured the LinkCheckerTransformerFactory: `linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements=["a:href","area:href","form:action","link:href","meta:content"]`

Some HTML on a page component:

```
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="/content/www-sitename/home.html" />
  <meta name="canonical" content="/content/www-sitename/home.html" />
</head>
```

When visited, only the link:href has been rewritten, meta:content is unchanged:

```
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.sitename.com/home.html" />
  <meta name="canonical" content="/content/www-sitename/home.html" />
</head>
```

Worth noting is that the link:href was not rewritten prior to configuring the `linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements` to include it.  Why did this change work for link:href, but not meta:content.  Aside from creating a custom rewrite filter, what can be done to get links in meta:content attributes to be rewritten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*nerd* answer is correct, by default the internal Sling mechanism responsible for parsing HTML (htmlparser) supports only following tags: `a`, `area`, `form`, `base`, `link`, `script`, `body`, so even if you add `meta:content` to the LinkChecker configuration, CQ won't recognize the `<meta>` as a tag which needs processing.

In order to reconfigure `htmlparser`, create a node named `generator-htmlparser` under `/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default` with following properties:

- jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
- includeTags = [`A`, `AREA`, `FORM`, `BASE`, `LINK`, `SCRIPT`, `BODY`, `META`]

The `includeTags` property should be multivalued, so you can add other tags in the future.

If you don't want to override the content under `/libs`, create your own rewriter configuration:

1. Copy `/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default` and its children to `/apps/YOURAPP/config/rewriter/my-rewriter`.
2. Set `order` property on the `my-rewriter` to `1`.
3. Create `generator-htmlparser` under the `my-rewriter` as above.

Comment: Thank you both!  Is there any way to do this without modifying _libs_?  I've tried to create _/apps/cq/config/rewriter/default/generator-htmlparser_, following your instructions at the location under _apps_, but this did not work.

Comment: Thanks again, @Tomek.  I have a follow up question regarding the rewriting of URLs containing `jcr:content`.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220078/sling-mapping-rewrite-rules-do-not-rewrite-jcrcontent-paths

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add meta tag to the htmplparser generator.

see my question and answer: [How to add additional element to htmlparser generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673616/how-to-add-additional-element-to-htmlparser-generator)